# Optimal tree data structure for merging real-time sequential data

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, tree, real-time

I am working on a project in C where I have to store, sort and update the information obtained in real time. The maximum amount of information I can have is defined. The information obtained is `<key,value1,value2>`, but is sorted according to the key and value1. The key would indicate the start of the node and value1 would indicate its size.
The basic operations I would need to perform here are insertion, search, deletion but most importantly merge if I find a sequential information.
As an example, in an empty structure, I input `<100,1>` - this will create one node.
Next if I input `<102,2>` - this will create another node. So 2 nodes would exist in the tree.
Next if I input `<101,1>` - this should at the end create only one node in the tree: `<100,4>`

I also want to separately sort these nodes according to their value2. Note that value2 could be updated in real-time.

I was thinking about B+ tree because of its logarithmic performance in all cases since all leaf nodes are at the same level. And by the use of separate doubly linked list, I can create separate links to sort the nodes according to value2. 
But the overhead for sorting according to `<key,value1>` would be I always have to do a search operation; for merge, for add and for delete.

Any thoughts/suggestions about this?

Comment: Why not use a database for this kind of thing, instead of a hand programmed data-structure?

Comment: In general trees can be quiet poor data structures on modern hardware due to poor cache locality/utilization.

Comment: It's really pointless asking for the "optimal" solution when you haven't even specified the data types, data ranges, memory restrictions, system architecture, insertion performance requirements, query performance requirements, etc...

Comment: @paddy key, value1,value2 are all unsigned int.

Comment: If you think that's sufficient information for anyone to provide useful feedback, you are mistaken.